# Server prints endless newlines when client disconnects

Tags: python, sockets

I am in the process of creating a server but I have hit wall and can't seem to climb over it...

The current code I have works very well until a user disconnects from the server. An endless amount of \n are printed and I can not seem to figure out why.

I do know that the problem lies in the recv function. I believe it has something to do with my threading but I just can not seem to figure out what it is.

Here is the code, I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

```
def recv(self, obj, addr, s):
    while True:
        try:print obj.recv(1024)
        except:pass

def connect(self, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(1)
    self.clearscreen()

    print "Waiting for connections..."
    while True:
        obj, addr = s.accept()
        verify = obj.recv(1024)
        if verify == "ea25364e2dab91b40ae4f73163854b5d":
            print "\n"+str(addr) + " has connected.\n "
            self.conns[addr] = obj
            try:
                Thread(target=self.handle, args=(obj, addr, s)).start()
                Thread(target=self.recv, args=(obj, addr, s)).start()
            except:pass
        else:pass
```

Comment: `except:pass` -- augh! my eyes are burning!

Comment: Ok, I've recovered.  Do not use `except:pass` ever.  It masks real problems.  It's a part of the [anti-idioms](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except), too.

Comment: Sorry, its a bad habit with the except:pass.

Comment: Fix it, and your debugging will be much easier.

Comment: +1 on fixing it. @pydsigner's answer will solve your problem when `recv` returns empty (a normal disconnect), but you'll have the exact same problem when `recv` throws (a low-level error).

Comment: Actually, he'll have worse: An infinite loop.

Comment: @pydsigner: It's exactly the same infinite loop he has today on empty `recv`. But I suppose it will be less obvious without all the newlines to tell him something is wrong, so in that sense you're right, it's worse.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How did you expect the client threads to ever return, given that they call a function that just loops forever and cannot possibly return or raise?

Comment: @abarnert That reminds me of another problem he'd have: memory-gulp.

Comment: @pydsigner: Well, yeah, he is permanently leaking a thread (meaning around 0.5-2MB, depending on the platform) per client connection. But really, before he can actually run out of swap space doing that, the thrashing caused by swapping thousands of thread stacks in and out to disk to run his infinite loops is going to slow the machine down enough that nobody can connect anyway, right? :)

Comment: @abarnert, IMO, the most pernicious problem would be a trivial typo.  Misspelling a function or module name would cause a `NameError` to be thrown and ignored.  I can see it now: "program all of a sudden seems to jump out of the body and never even calls `foo()` when you can see it's right there!"

Comment: @BrianCain Well, the `try:`/`except: pass` is actually inside the loop, so it never jumps outside of the body; instead, a trivial typo will make it spin forever in an infinite loop. And, since his code will spin forever in an infinite loop _even without any typos_, it's hard to argue that this is an additional problem. Of course you're completely right in general, but in this case, there are other things wrong that make the usual wrongness less relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is, you continually get and print data from an empty buffer. You ought to check what you are recv()ing to make sure you actually got something.

```
data = obj.recv(1024)
if not data:
    return
print data
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel really stupid for missing this. Once again thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you would, please mark my answer with the checkmark.